# A warning of tensorflow running on gpu

Tags: tensorflow

When I run my code on gpu, I got a warning ***every step***. Like below:

```
2018-02-09 12:59:58.635500: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:3100]
```

This warning didn't happen until I add the bn layer into my model. I don't know the reason of that. And I didn't got answer from google.

And at the begining of my terminal output, there are some other outputs:

```
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 10.71GiB
2018-02-09 12:46:34.030887: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Begin Training!!!
0
pickle 0 load finished
2018-02-09 12:47:47.429015: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.25GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2018-02-09 12:47:47.429015: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.05GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2018-02-09 12:47:47.475816: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.02GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2018-02-09 12:47:47.475816: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 34.84MiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2018-02-09 12:47:47.491416: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.05GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2018-02-09 12:47:47.569416: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 85.05MiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
[step 000000] loss 4484.4204     lr 0.00500
[step 000001] loss 14606.2910    lr 0.00500
2018-02-09 12:47:54.823428: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 256.0KiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2018-02-09 12:47:54.823428: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:3100] 
[step 000002] loss 10781.2871    lr 0.00500
2018-02-09 12:47:55.931030: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 256.0KiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2018-02-09 12:47:55.946630: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:3100] 
[step 000003] loss 2583.5710     lr 0.00500
```

Comment: Practically, this is usually solved by reducing the batch size

Comment: @Maxim Thank you! When I run the code again, the terminal didn't appear the W again. I just don't know why my GPU memory was allocated by 6 times. It never happens before. Is there something wrong in my GPU?

Comment: Most probably, tensorflow allocated the memory and intended to reuse it for future runs, but the new allocations forced it to free that memory and re-allocate a new chunk. So you should read the warning like this: "I tried my best to optimize it, but it didn't work out. I wish you had more memory"

Comment: I see. Thanks for your replying!